# If we have an $n \times m$ matrix $A$, is Col(A) a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading through Axler's Linear Algebra book.

I believe that the answer to my question is **no**.

[This link](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenber/RangeNull.pdf) shows that if we have an $n \times m$ matrix $A$, then Col(A) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but I cannot come up with a similar proof to show that the same holds for $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. For example, consder $m > n$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for a n-by m matrix any vectors in Col(A) is in $\mathbb{R^n}$ therefore Col(A) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and Row(A) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks.

Comment: @Hat That was a nice thought! You are welcome, Bye.